# Error: `position_jitterdodge()` requires at least one aesthetic to dodge by

Tags: r, ggpubr

I try to draw a barplot grouped figure, but I can't, my error is,
"`position_jitterdodge()` requires at least one aesthetic to dodge by". Can anyone help me? Here is the sample of my data and my try to draw barplot code. My expected output is sth like the graph below.[image]

```
library(ggpubr)

d<-data.frame(Average=c(3,1.5,4, 6,
                    2,5.4,3.1,0.9,
                    4.6,3.3,2.8,1.9,
                    2.1,3.7,4.4,5.2),
          Size=c("1750","1750","1750","1750",
                 "2000","2000","2000","2000",
                 "2500","2500","2500","2500",
                 "3000","3000","3000","3000"),
          Group=c("P1","P1","P1","P1",
                  "S1","S1","S1","S1",
                  "P2","P2","P2","P2",
                  "S2","S2","S2","S2"))


ggbarplot(
  d, x = "Size", y = "Average", 
  add = c("mean_sd", "jitter"), 
  add.params = list(shape = "supp"),
  fill= "Group", palette = c("#807F7F", "#BF504D"),
  position = position_dodge(0.8)
)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work with the data you provided.  Also, could you identify what you want the output to look like?  What are you trying to jitter and dodge?

Comment: which package is ggbarplot in? It can be cleaner to do this directly in ggplot2.

Comment: the package is ggpubr

Comment: @DaveArmstrong identified Dave, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

1. `group` has 4 values with only 2 colors assigned.
2. The variable 'supp' does not exist in your data.

Otherwise your code should work:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

d<-data.frame(Average=c(3,1.5,4, 6,
                        2,5.4,3.1,0.9,
                        4.6,3.3,2.8,1.9,
                        2.1,3.7,4.4,5.2),
              Size=c("1750","1750","1750","1750",
                     "2000","2000","2000","2000",
                     "2500","2500","2500","2500",
                     "3000","3000","3000","3000"),
              Group=c("P","P","S","S", "P","P","S","S", "P","P","S","S","P","P","S","S")
              )


ggbarplot(
  d, x = "Size", y = "Average", 
  add = c("mean_sd", "jitter"), 
  add.params = list(shape = "Group"),
  fill= "Group", palette = c("#807F7F", "#BF504D"),
  position = position_dodge(0.8)
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>